# jersey-spring3 (2.25.1) produces "Failed startup of context" error in jetty-9.3.3

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jetty, maven-3

I am using Jersey-2.25.1 with Spring framework 4.3.5 in Jetty-9.3.3 environment. My OS is Centos 7 and JDK 8. During deployment time, I am receiving the following error:

*Note: The following error occurred, only when jersey-spring3 dependency is added in the pom.xml.*

```
Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5d37aa0f{/test-service,file:///.../test-service/,STARTING}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///.../test-service/WEB-INF/lib/asm-all-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:925)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:988)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:970)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:921)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is it problem with Jetty's /lib/annotations/asm-5.0.1.jar and asm-commons-5.0.1.jar or jersey-spring3.jar?

Comment: Did you exclude all the Spring 3 dependencies from jersey-spring3?

Comment: @peeskillet, No. Actually, we would like to keep our own Spring dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked into module-info.class file

```
$ javap -v  ./module-info.class 
...
class org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.all.debug.module-info
minor version: 0
major version: 53
```

So, it is compiled with java 9, and it is a part [new module system in java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start).

Anyway, there is no use in scanning this file (especially with java 8).

I fixed the issue by excluding `asm-all-repackaged.jar` from jetty annotation scanning:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
   <configuration>
     <webApp>
       ...
       <webInfIncludeJarPattern>.*/^(asm-all-repackaged)[^/]*\.jar$</webInfIncludeJarPattern>
     </webApp>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is [documentation about webInfIncludeJarPattern](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp)

Comment: Anyhow, I did not add the above solution. I have explicitly declared asm-all-repackaged-2.4.0 on my pom.xml as dependency to **resolve** this issue. <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>‌<artifactId>asm-al‌​l-repackaged</artifa‌​ctId> <version>2.4‌​.0</version></depend‌​ency>. Now, it is OK.